# How to get the validator's controltovalidate attribute in ASP.NET codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

In the codebehind of my page I create a list of errors instead of using the validationsummary with it's limited styling.

Here is my code I use for this:

```
Panel_feedback.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in' role='alert'>"));
Panel_feedback.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>×</span></button>"));
Panel_feedback.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<h2>ERROR!</h2>"));
Panel_feedback.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<ul class='fa-ul'>"));

foreach (IValidator error in this.Validators)
  {
     if (!error.IsValid)
         Panel_feedback.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<li><i class='fa-li fa fa-times-circle'></i>" + error.ErrorMessage + "</li>"));
   }
Panel_feedback.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</ul>"));
```

It seems like the error object should have a property like "controltovalidate" or something, but this isn't the case. The reason I want to know what the controltovalidate target is because I want to change the border red so the user will see which textbox is wrong.

Here is an example of one of my validators:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_name" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Vul uw naam in" Display="none" ControlToValidate="TextBox_name"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting to `BaseValidator` instead of `IValidator`, this should have more details for your needs.

See [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
foreach (BaseValidator error in this.Validators)
{
    if (error.IsValid)
        continue;

    Panel_feedback.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<li><i class='fa-li fa fa-times-circle'></i>" + error.ErrorMessage + "</li>"));
    string failedControlID = error.ControlToValidate;
    // ...
}
```